# Dayweek.java:9: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Помогите, пжл, устранить нижеследующую ошибку

```
Dayweek.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
      ^
  symbol:   class SimpleDateFormat
  location: class Dayweek
Dayweek.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                                    ^
  symbol:   class SimpleDateFormat
  location: class Dayweek
Dayweek.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(dayWeek));
                             ^
  symbol:   class SimpleDateFormat
  location: class Dayweek
3 errors
```

Сама программа имеет вид:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dayweek {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String date = "17.11.2016";
        
      // Переводим строку в дату  
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
      Date dayWeek = null;
      try {
          dayWeek = format.parse(date);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      
      // Вывод дня недели даты на экран
      System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(dayWeek));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не хватает импорта используемого вами класса:

`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

*P.S. В дальнейшем просьба самостоятельно пытаться разобраться с такими очевидными ошибками.*

Comment: Премного благодарен! Я только начал изучать Java

Comment: @Werhowen, также чтобы ваш вопрос не висел в списке неотвеченных, отметьте ответ "галочкой" (пометить, как решение вопроса), если он решает вашу проблему.